# PHP function to calculate number of parameters passed to a function

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is there a PhP function that can count the number of parameters passed to another function?
for example

```
function tobeCounted ("numberOne","numberTwo","numberThree")
{
 //do something with the parameters
}
```

a function that will count the number of parameters passed to the function above then return three or the indexes of the parameters or parameters themseleves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `func_num_args()` then you get the amount of arguments, rather than `func_get_args` that gets you the array of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

[func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need these:

func_num_args — Returns the number of arguments passed to the function

func_get_args — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list

From here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

Answer (score 1):

Or more directly: [func_num_args](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
func_num_args()
```

Use this to get the number of parameters passed